# Restrictive filtering array in Javascript/TypeScript for a relationship path problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filtering

I have a filtering problem I am trying to solve in TS/JS and stuck.

I want to filter an array with possible paths with an array of keywords. And it should not have any thing else other than these keywords.

```
let paths = ['Domain.travelers', 'Domain.travelers.products', 'Domain.travelers.remarks.products', 'Domain.products', 'Domain.vehicle.travelers.products'];
    
let keywords = ['travelers', 'products'];
```

When filter is applied, it should only return:

```
['Domain.travelers', 'Domain.travelers.products', 'Domain.products']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find docs about functions I used here:

- [Array - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [String - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

```js
const paths = ['Domain.travelers', 'Domain.travelers.products', 'Domain.travelers.remarks.products', 'Domain.products', 'Domain.vehicle.travelers.products'];

const keywords = ['travelers', 'products'];

const results = paths.filter(path =>
  path.split('.').slice(1).every(
    pathPart => keywords.includes(pathPart)
  )
);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Definitely points me in the right direction. Building up on it, is there a way to reprevent paths with duplicate parts to be filtered. Like Domain.products.products if keywords only have one products keywords. But acceptable with keywords have more than one keywords of the same type.

Comment: there are multiple implementations possible for this that comes to my mind. For each path you could copy the keywords array and remove a keyword as soon as it match a pathPart, preventing it from matching other pathParts. You could also build a map pathPart => count and check if any pathPart count exceeds what's in keywords