# Restrictive filtering array in Javascript/TypeScript for a relationship path problem preventing duplication keywords in paths

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filtering

I have a filtering problem I am trying to solve in TS/JS and stuck.

[This is building on to an earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71240772/restrictive-filtering-array-in-javascript-typescript-for-a-relationship-path-pro/71240933#71240933)

But I have one more requirement to prevent duplicate paths unless the keywords also have multiple instances of the string, like if

```
let paths = ['Domain.travelers', 'Domain.travelers.products', 'Domain.travelers.remarks.products', 'Domain.products', 'Domain.vehicle.travelers.products', 'Domain.products.products'];
    
let keywords = ['travelers', 'products'];
```

When filter is applied, it should only return:

```
['Domain.travelers', 'Domain.travelers.products', 'Domain.products']
```

But if keywords are :

```
let keywords = ['travelers', 'products', 'products'];
```

then when filter is applied, it should return:

```
['Domain.travelers', 'Domain.travelers.products', 'Domain.products', 'Domain.products.products']
```

Thank you!

Comment: you get already the wanted result with the solution of the refrenced question. btw, why twice products?

Comment: In a scenario where there are 2 keywords of the same type. For if products in keywords array twice then Domain.products.products is valid but if products is in keyword array once then it isnt.

Comment: nice rule, but does it apply here?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but yes it does. At the moment I think I can maybe apply filter twice, first to get the possible paths then filter to see if paths have duplicates when it shouldnt.

Comment: no, i mean the rule makse no sense. the array ahs no meaing in sense of position of the word. it acts more like a set of strings, and two same strings are not possible, and what is more important, not necessary to ge the result. maybe is do not see the problem or the given data is not complete for getting a difference of the earlier solution with an array of strings.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NabKBm) meet your needs? Please test against the use cases you care about (it would be unfortunate for you to open additional questions for each subsequent requirement you find).  It it works for you I can write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the question to clearly demonstrate a case where this code fails.

Comment: jcalz, thank you so much! This is 100% exactly what I wanted. Apologies to everyone about my question wording, I tend to waffle a lot when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
const computeAcceptablePaths = (paths: string[], keywords: string[]) => paths.filter(
    path => {
        const keywordCounts: Record<string, number> = {};
        for (const kw of keywords) { keywordCounts[kw] = (keywordCounts[kw] || 0) + 1; }
        for (const pathComponent of path.split(".").slice(1)) {
            if (!keywordCounts[pathComponent]) return false;
            keywordCounts[pathComponent]--;
        }
        return true;
    }
);
```

The general approach here is to take the `keywords` array and convert it into a data structure which counts how many times each distinct keyword appears. So if `keywords` is `['travelers', 'products']`, then `keywordCounts` is `{travelers: 1, products: 1}`.  And if `keywords` is `['travelers', 'products', 'products']`, then `keywordCounts` is `{travelers: 1, products: 2}`.

For any given `path` from the `paths` array, we will [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it into an array of `pathComponent`s separated by the `"."` delimiter, and ignore the initial `"Domain"` component (by taking the [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) starting with the second path component).  So `"Domain.travelers.products"` should become `["travelers", "products"]`.  Conceptually we could then turn this array into the same type of data structure where we count how many times each component appears, like `{travelers: 1, products: 1}` for `"Domain.travelers.products"`, or `{products: 2}` for `"Domain.products.products"`.  (We don't actually do this step, but it's the same idea)

And we filter the `paths` array by keeping each `path` if and only if each component appears at most as many times as the count from `keywordCounts`.  We do that by iterating through each path component and decrementing the corresponding count from `keywordCounts`.  If we ever hit a path component where the corresponding `keywordCounts` entry is either missing or zero, then the path is not valid (and we return `false` from the filter callback).  Otherwise, if we make it through all the path components without this happening, then the path is valid (and we return `true` from the filter callback).

Let's verify that it works as desired:

```
console.log(computeAcceptablePaths(paths, ['travelers', 'products']));
// ["Domain.travelers", "Domain.travelers.products", "Domain.products"] 

console.log(computeAcceptablePaths(paths, ['travelers', 'products', 'products']));
// ["Domain.travelers", "Domain.travelers.products", 
//  "Domain.products", "Domain.products.products"]
```

Looks good!  In the case where `keywords` has `products` only once, the `"Domain.products.products"` path is rejected, but in the case where `products` appears twice in `keywords`, the `"Domain.products.products"` path is accepted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-mAJD6zVy+UKJTKFWqdU2rU2w3QBG0oj0ykI0SsnB9ZZwAHoJxhdZEtCJdBxdcNZxohH3F+YnCPlxBV544jvqWlsCiqyBaDW6w2CsVSuVKjUQPV2p32t3ewuxNwh9vQsMCGHUIx1hKcZznAJ+yXFcII3IIgKUXd9wcBDECQiDUMPFxdUSHAgA)